# Making Property of my Usercontrol Bindable

Tags: silverlight

i have created a custom user control which im using on my main xaml control:

```
<Controls:CustomControl  Width="200" Height="20" 
TotalCount="{Binding TotalRecordCount}" SuccessCount="{Binding ValidationCount}" ErrorCount="{Binding ValidationErrorCount}" Margin="0,5,0,0"  HorizontalAlignment="Left"> 
</Controls:CustomControl>
```

I wanted to make the private variables of my custom usercontrol being ErrorCount,SuccessCount and total count(which are of type int32) Bindable so i can bind values to them. Right now when i try to bind it to my item source it gives the following error e exception message is "Object of type 'System.Windows.Data.Binding' cannot be converted to type 'System.Int32'

Many thanks,
Michelle

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to implement the Properties using `DependencyProperty` don't use private variables to hold these values. Here is an example:-

```
    #region public int SuccessCount

    public int SuccessCount
    {
        get { return (int)GetValue(SuccessCountProperty); }
        set { SetValue(SuccessCountProperty, value); }
    }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty SuccessCountProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register(
            "SuccessCount",
            typeof(int),
            typeof(CustomControl),
            new PropertyMetadata(0, OnSuccessCountPropertyChanged));

    private static void OnSuccessCountPropertyChanged(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        CustomControl source = d as CustomControl;
        int value = (int)e.NewValue;

        // Do stuff when new value is assigned.
    }
    #endregion public int SuccessCount
```

Answer (score 0):

In order for a property to be "Bindable", meaning that you can set it using DataBinding, that property needs to be a `Dependency Property`. For more info on Dependency Properties, please check [this MSDN article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms752914.aspx).

hope this helps :)